# ploting power function of a sign test

Tags: r, p-value, hypothesis-test

I am trying to plot the power function of a sign test. The code I have is already this one:

```
library(BSDA)  # for SIGN.test()

M_values <- seq(-1, 1, by = 0.1)
sign_rank_test_p<-vector("numeric",length=length(M_values))
sign_test_p<-vector("numeric", length=length(M_values))
n<-1000
lower_bounds <- matrix(nrow=n,ncol=length(M_values))
upper_bounds <- matrix(nrow=n,ncol=length(M_values))
center <- matrix(nrow=n,ncol=length(M_values))
for (i in seq_along(M_values)) {
  for (j in 1:n){
    M <- M_values[i]
    value <- rnorm(1, mean = M, sd = 1)
    lower_bounds[j,i] <- value-0.01
    upper_bounds[j,i] <- value+0.01
    center[j,i] <- (lower_bounds[j,i] + upper_bounds[j,i]) / 2
  }
  sign_test_p[i]<-SIGN.test(center[,i],md=0,alternative = "greater")$p.value
  sign_rank_test_p[i]<-wilcox.test(center[,i], mu = 0, alternative = "greater")$p.value
}


# Create a data frame to store the results
results_df <- data.frame(M = M_values,
                         sign_test_p_value = sign_test_p,
                         signed_rank_test_p_value = sign_rank_test_p)
```

This gives the p values for the sign test. We generated 1000 p-values for values of M that is between -1 and 1.

What I want now is to plot the power function for the sign test and take some conclusions about it but I dont know how to do it. Is it with pwr.r.test or power.sign.test?

Comment: `SIGN.test` is not a base R function. When using functions that are not base R functions please start the scripts with a call to `library(pkgname)` in order to load the packages needed. (Already done, I have edited the question.)

Comment: I don't see any evidence that you know what a power function means. Perhaps if you had included some comments or explained your plan I would have come to a different conclusion. Have you tried searching for a prior answer at CrossValidated.com?